# Replacing / toggling a div with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been pulling my hair out over this problem. I have a div which contains a table, I want to have a button somewhere on the page which when clicked replaces the table with a map image.
I have been using this code here successfully with demo data:

```
  function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
  d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  if (d2.style.display == "none") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    d2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/timmehnz/pen/MKVVLJ)

However whenever I implement it into my Wordpress site it doesn't work. The page I am testing this on is the following: [Development Site](http://188.226.146.65/kft/?page_id=340#ffs-tabbed-11)

Any help is appreciated
-Tim

Answer (score 2):

Problem on your development site is a typo on quote,

You are writing:

```
javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('tablepress-1`,'map-1')
```

whereas it should be:

```
javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('tablepress-1','map-1')
```

notice the 2nd quote.

Comment: Isnt your second "quote" here actually an accent?

Comment: exactly that's what he has written in his actual code, which is a typo.

Comment: Moreover you shouldn't be exposing your public ip like this.

Comment: That's weird, and thanks for pointing that out - but here is a copy and paste of my code on the dev site:

<p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;"> <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('tablepress-1','map-1')">Swap Divs</a> </p>

There is no typo there

Comment: I mean in your second example, you say *"whereas it should be: `javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('tablepress-1′,'map-1')`"* ...but your second quote is still wrong

Comment: No it's still the same issue, the console is outputting what you noted above with the accent, however there is no accent as I showed above with my copy paste.

Comment: But look at my paste of the code above @DelightedD0D. They are only quotes

Comment: @TimmehNZ I know, im talking to Sachin, trying to make him see this is not correct

Comment: hmm @DelightedD0D when i copy pasted my above code in console, it shows accent. may be because i copy pasted the same accent code twice, but edited the accent second time, which reflets when you see it as text (not copy it). This can be a stackoverflow error.

Comment: @TimmehNZ i edited your code in inspect element and it actually swaps, so it is working fine after replacing..

Comment: @DelightedD0D see this is what i see before loading your edit, https://unsee.cc/teniguso/

Comment: What kind of device are you using? Im on a mac and it was definately the wrong character, maybe your device doesnt show it for some reason or they look the same

Comment: @Sachin, you are right. I can also edit it in inspector and it works...no wonder I was going mad. There is something happening in Wordpress that is causing my correctly formatted quote mark to be converted to an accent on publication.

Comment: @DelightedD0D and see this is how your edit looks like: https://unsee.cc/nesamugo/ 
  I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Ah, yup thats why then :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D thats why then? bug for ubuntu machine?

Comment: @TimmehNZ its doubtful that that single character was converted by WP, you probably copied it from somewhere weird, but glad your fixed up :)

Comment: @Sachin must be, I have a ubuntu machine at work, im gonna look at it again when I go in in a few

Comment: @DelightedD0D please update me as well if you find anything :)

Comment: @Sachin yep, the accent looks just like the single quote on our ubuntu machine at work. I couldnt find any articles about this online but I did find [one that seems to indicate that pressing the single quote twice on ubuntu produces an accent character](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172828/typing-twice-turns-it-into-%C2%B4). Maybe thats what you did?

Comment: i copy pasted same accent code twice, but replaced accent with quote the second time. accent is used for representing code in stackoverflow, so there might be some parsing and rendering issue?